# Can I delete room owned by other?

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow, chat

Can I delete other owners' rooms on stackoverflow chat?

Comment: What room are we talking about? Or the simple answer: Don't go into that room.

Comment: Wait - you want to delete the **ROOM** or remove a user from that room?

Comment: You could have asked the same Qn in an appropriate way and prevented the pouring in downvotes.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Given that it is a feature-request (and the nature of the matter), downvotes are inevitable.

Comment: If you dislike chat so much, stop going there.

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaaa??!

Comment: @apaderno, why did you change the tag to [meta-tag:support] from [meta-tag:feature-request]? I find the new status as "support" historically confusing- especially because it has the [meta-tag:status-declined] tag on it.

Comment: @starball Because it's not requesting a feature, but asking if it's possible to delete chat rooms owned by other users.

Comment: @apaderno I'm not sure if that "respects the original author's intent" because I'm not sure if the original author's intent was to ask for support. I don't find it hard to understand this question as a way of politely asking for something (feature-request). How were you _certain_ that the original author intended to ask for support instead of a feature?

Comment: @starball The first revision said *Please suggest me .* A politely way to ask for a feature request would probably contain a sentence similar to *May you please allow to delete chat room created from other users?* not *Please suggest me.*

Comment: @apaderno Ah. Understood. Thanks for taking the time to help me understand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I think stackoverflow is for programming purpose not for fun . Here some people just chat for fun .

As far as Stack Overflow *itself* is concerned, you're right. [We hate fun there](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

As far as the chat is concerned, you're wrong. The *whole point* of it is to be a [bit more relaxed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) than the main site.

> Can i delete other owners room on stackoverflow?

No, you very much can't. If there's a room that's absolutely inappropriate, feel free to be specific, and we'll look at it. But if your only issue with a room is that people are having fun in it, then I guess it's a good thing that we don't allow arbitrary users to go on a chat room deletion rampage.

Comment: I smell a Reversal badge. (+1)

Answer (score 8):

You can't kick users out of a room that you do not own.  You can however simply ignore messages from specific users.

If you click on the user in chat - you should see a link saying -

> ignore this user (everywhere)

[image]

Click it and you won't have any more fun with that user in chat :P

Comment: But i am not owner of that room....

Comment: Hah, I know who that guy is.

Comment: @ChiragRaval: You can ignore users everywhere, regardless of ownership

Comment: @YannisRizos even, i too know him but i have never seen him in chat room, strange

Comment: @Lucifer my guess is _that guy_ goes to chat almost exclusively to complain to moderators about something that can't be handled with flags :)

Comment: @gnat that is good to hear, i would like to talk with him too as i know him since last 6-7 months

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to get rid of the room all together, you simply can not do that.  The only thing you will be able to do is to flag one of the posts in that chat room and explain to a moderator why you believe this room should not be open.

I should warn you that just because some users are having some fun it doesn't mean that the room should be destroyed.  It's much better for them to be letting off steam in a chat room rather than on some post in the site.

You can't get angry because you disagree with someone else's behavior on the internet.

Comment: `You can't get angry because you disagree with someone else's behavior on the internet.` **Since when, did I miss a memo or something?**

Comment: @yan - Yes - I was angry at you so I didn't forward it :P

Answer (score 2):

> Can i delete other owners room on stackoverflow?

No, not unless you are a moderator.

> I think stackoverflow is for programming purpose not for fun . Here some people just chat for fun .

You can't tell others what to do this way. Let them have their fun! IIRC, chat was created to move the "fun" and long discussions out of the main site.

Chat has these advantages:

- Extended discussions go out of the public view
- A lot of this "fun" in chat **leads to community-building and bonding between members.**
- Can hold all sorts of off topic stuff that would otherwise plague the main sites

In fact, chat keeps these "fun" guys out of *your* way. It's their *own* time that they're "wasting". Let them do so.

Comment: `"bonding between members"` - Care to elaborate? What *really* goes on in the TL? huh?

Comment: @Lix: **ALERT ALERT we have been compromised calling all mods ban Lix ASAP and wipe clean all TL related comments**

Comment: @Lix We mainly discuss the bonding between members of the immunoglobulin and integrin supergene families.

Comment: @TimManishEarth Don't worry about it, he'd _never_ get past the twelve headed thingamadongdong guarding the entrance to the room.

Comment: @TimPost Ah, so THAT's why you made Cerberus a mod?